# Grouping and summing cloudwatch log insights query

Tags: python, regex, reporting, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have about 10k logs from log insights in the below format (cannot post actual logs due to privacy rules). I am using boto3 to query the logs.

Log insights query:

```
filter @message like /ERROR/
```

Output Logs format:

```
 timestamp:ERROR <some details>Apache error....<error details> 
 timestamp:ERROR <some details>Connection error.... <error details> 
 timestamp:ERROR <some details>Database error....<error details>
```

What I need is to group the errors having similar substring (like group by Connection error, Apache error, Database error) or any other similar errors and get a sum of those.

Expected output:

```
  Apache error      130
  Database error    2253
  Connection error  3120
```

Is there some regex or any other way I can use to pull out similar substrings and group them and get the sum? Either in python or in log insights.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to say without seeing the source of your data but you can extract values from logs with a logs insight query like

```
filter @logStream like 'SOMEHOST'
| parse @message /<EventID.*?>(?<event_id>\d+)<\/EventID>/
| stats count() by event_id
```

In this case I was parsing windows event logs to count how many of each event type happened

```
----------------------
| event_id | count() |
|----------|---------|
| 7036     | 80      |
| 7001     | 4       |
| 7002     | 4       |
| 6013     | 1       |
| 7039     | 1       |
| 7009     | 1       |
| 7000     | 1       |
| 7040     | 2       |
| 7045     | 1       |
----------------------
```

This query just looked for the event ID xml element. In your case you would need to look at your data to see how best to identify and extract your error. but if the error is in a format that has a field you can extract it. Even if there is no field you could still use a regex if there is a pattern to the data